# Remove part of message string BEFORE and AFTER in logstash config filter

Tags: substring, logstash, gsub

Message: `/merlion/dpa2/cn133ta/j4_sryuo/j4_02_sv_ip`

I am trying to find a way to remove the strings BEFORE and AFTER a defined string in a message.

In this message, the constant value is dpa2, and I want to discard anything BEFORE dpa2(inclusive), and the "cn133ta/". Only want to retain "j4_sryuo/j4_02_sv_ip".

The position of cn133ta will be of dynamic value, so it is not a constant string. Hope that makes sense.

At the moment, I have tried the gsub below:

```
mutate { gsub => [ "dir_path", "/[^./]+/tpa2/", "/" ] }
```

But I'm having trouble finding a way to discard the AFTER string, in this case "cn133ta/".

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
mutate { gsub => [ "dir_path", "^.*?/dpa2/[^/]+/", "" ] }
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/78OPuU/1)

If the `dpa2` subpart is right after the first subpart use your approach,

```
^/[^/]+/dpa2/[^/]+/
 ^^^^^^
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/78OPuU/2).

**Pattern details**

- `^` - start of string
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `/dpa2/` - a literal string
- `[^/]+/` - 1+ chars other than `/` and then a `/`.